# Creating interactive charts in Flash

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I'm looking to display some data in the form of charts (line graphs, pie charts etc). I also require them to have a certain amount of interactivity (pan, zoom etc.).

For these requirements, will Adobe Flex be enough for me, or would I need to use flash?

A little research told me that building charts in Flex is easy, but can they be made interactive without using Flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex is just a framework on top of Flash. So, yes anything you want to do in Flash you can do in Flex as well.

In addition there are some not too difficult ways of panning/zooming on charts. To get you started, here's an extension of Flex Charts where someone added zooming functionality.

http://blog.ninjacaptain.com/2010/03/flex-chart-zoom-window/

Answer (score 1):

Check out Fusion Charts for flex, or AnyChart for Flex their AnyStock product is pretty much what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into AnyChart. I did look into Fusion Charts. While it looks great and very mature, its cost is prohibitive.

Comment: It depends on your model, really, web app, desktop application, software as a service, I use it for a BI tool, which I charge for, so as such on AnyCharts Saas Model it works out to $30 a user per year.

Any chart is my preferred of the 2 anyway. Any chart types I am missing I can build from scratch anyway. So its not a big deal.

But yes anychart is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

flex is good enough for this job,
check out http://chart.sqlcode.org (MultiChart), it is easier to interact than the expensive chart solutions.